# Proc Export to Excel - Multiple tables to one xlsx file on one sheet

Tags: excel, sas, export, proc

I want to export different excel tables to only one sheet in  excel workbook

Comment: [plese consult help section on how to formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can append all your tables to one table, then export the single table using `proc export`.

If you want to export each table to a separate sheet; If you are running on SAS 9.3 M2 or earlier you will need to install a SAS [hotfix](http://support.sas.com/kb/51/580.html).

```
proc export data=sashelp.class outfile='c:\sastest\myfile.xlsx' dbms=xlsx;
   sheet=class;
run;

proc export data=sashelp.shoes outfile='c:\sastest\myfile.xlsx' dbms=xlsx;
   sheet=shoes;
run;
```

Comment: Append is not possible if variables are different in tables

Comment: if the column types are not the same in all the tables, you can make all variables Characters for the append to work.

Answer (score 1):

The a similar question answered on SAS Communities [site](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Proc-Export-to-Excel-Multiple-tables-to-one-xlsx-file-on/m-p/187081#M47512). You can use either `proc export` or `ods tagsets.excelxp`